# Number of elements in a subgroup of two permutation groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A=\left\{\beta \in S_{5}\ |\ \beta(1)=1,\beta(3)=3 \right\}.$ How many elements are in $A$? How many elements are in $A$ when $S_{5}$ is replaced by $A_n$ for $n\geq 4$.

My thought for the first part: there are 3 ways to have a 2-cycle times 1-cycle (since 1 and 3 must be in 1-cycles), and $\frac{6}{3}=2$ ways to have a 3-cycle, and 1 way to have 3 1-cycles. Therefore, the total elements in $A$ is $6$

For $A_n$, I don't think there is such one, because if there is, then $A_n$ must contain disjoint $1$-cycles, which contradicts to the definition of a group of even permutation. If I'm wrong, I couldn't solve it for both cases when $n$ is even and odd, except for the base values, $n=4$ and $n=5$. Any help on this part would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  If you are permuting $n$ elements, but insist that $\beta(1)=1$ and $\beta(3)=3$, then in effect you are just permuting $n-2$ elements.  How many such permutations are there?  How many even permutations?

Note that it is not true to say that an even permutation cannot contain $1$-cycles.  For example, the identity is even and it contains nothing but $1$-cycles.  This is in fact the answer for $A_4$: your subgroup contains the identity only.

Comment: For $A_{n-2}$, the number of permutations is $(n-2)!$ The even permutations is $\frac{(n-2)!}{2}$. But I don't get why $A$ only contains the identity though. How about this permutation: (1) (3) (2,4)? I actually got 2 elements in the subgroup $A$ for the case $A_4$. Did I get the first question right?

Comment: The permutation $(1)(3)(2\ 4)$ is odd because it contains one transposition.  That's fine in $S_4$, but not in $A_4$.

Comment: Many thanks! So the correct answer should be $\frac{(n-2)!}{2}$ for the case $A_n$?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Thank you. Is $6$ for $S_5$ correct too?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks for your help. I'll try solving the general case $S_n$, and post the solution here if I get it.